# system time automagically resetting on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, systemd, ntp

ubuntu 16.04 server.  My first ubuntu, so yeah, ubuntu newbie factor.

System time on server is about 17 minutes fast.  I can reset it many various ways successfully at the command line.  In every case, within 15 or so seconds, it will be reset to the wrong time again.  systemd seems to be at the root of it. In message log:

```
systemd[20113]: Time has been changed
```

I assumed the culprit was timedatectl.  Made sure to disable and check:

```
root@portal:~# systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service

â systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d
           ââdisable-with-time-daemon.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)

root@portal:~# systemctl list-units|grep 'time-sync'
root@portal:~#
```

This:

```
root@portal:~# ntpdate -s 0.north-america.pool.ntp.org
root@portal:~# journal -f
```

Results in this:

```
Dec 08 20:04:18 portal sudo[4486]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened
for user root by owen(uid=0)
Dec 08 19:46:44 portal systemd[2814]: Time has been changed
Dec 08 19:46:44 portal ntpdate[4502]: step time server 171.66.97.126 offset -1098.814353 sec
Dec 08 20:05:35 portal systemd[2814]: Time has been changed
```

Notice the timestamp of each log entry...

What, pray tell, is resetting the time and where is it getting the ntp server setting, and why is it wrong???  I thought the large drift might be part of the issue, but it doesn;t match up with the number of minutes it's off...
TIA

Answer (score 2):

FTR, this turned out to be the date on the virtual server being wrong.  I had checked the hardware server itself and it was accurate, but the date/time via vmware  was off a weird increment.  Once I corrected this, everything settled down.